# Reformatting datetime

Tags: php, date, time

Ok, so I've got a time string like this:

2013-08-09T15:00:00

Now as far as I can tell, I'll need to convert this to a timestamp, before I can change the formatting - is that correct, or is there a shorter step? For example using one of the classes here:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/08/why-php-datetime-rocks

I'm not quite sure what the "T" represents (besides time, obviously) and I'm not sure what format that is.

I want to get it into standard 12 hour time.

Comment: that time is ISO 8601. "T" is to indicate time, to separate from date.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

```
$dt = new DateTime('2013-08-09T15:00:00');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

Comment: add "a" at the end of the ('Y-m-d h:i:s a') to indicate am or pm, the hour output will be in 12h format